# gzip and return as string

Tags: php, gzip, gzipstream

I want to compress some files with gzip in PHP..

It works as it should when the output file is saved into a file.. When the file is opened it looks like this

[image]

But not when the output is returned as a string.. Then the opened file looks like this.. Why is tar file showed inside the gzip file?

[image]

```
public function compress(){
    if($this->stream){
        return gzencode($this->data, 9);
    }
    else{
        $gz = gzopen('test.tar.gz', 'w9');
        gzwrite($gz, $this->data);
        gzclose($gz);
    }
}
```

## headers sent with string output to the browser

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Comment: I also tried it and it didn't created a tar inside the gzip file.

Comment: gzencode produces gzip archive(.gz) not gzip tar (.tar.gz). What you have there is a file with tar-19 in name. Are you sure those files are produced by the above script.

Comment: how do I solve it so the file as string behave like the created file?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a WinRAR file extension parsing issue.

In the first example your file is called `.tar.gz` and WinRAR knows how to handle both `tar` files and `gz` compression, so it is able to decompress the tar headers in memory and  retrieve a list of files contained within.

In your second example the file is called `.tar-19.gz`, so WinRAR happily deals with the gz compression but has no idea what format `tar-19` is supposed to be (it doesn't even try and guess from header heuristics)

I bet if you stream the file with a `tar.gz` extension it will open up just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that you looked into http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php

make sure that you have php version **PHP 4 >= 4.0.1, PHP 5**

```
 string gzcompress ( string $data [, int $level = -1 [, int $encoding = ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE ]] )
```

This function compress the given string using the ZLIB data format.

For details on the ZLIB compression algorithm see the document "» [ZLIB Compressed Data Format Specification version 3.3](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1950.html)" (RFC 1950).

```
<?php
$compressed = gzcompress('Compress me', 9);
echo $compressed;
?>
```

> **Note:**
>
> This is not the same as gzip compression, which includes some header
>   data. See gzencode() for gzip compression.

**Parameters**

> data
>
> ```
> The data to compress.
> ```

**level**

> The level of compression. Can be given as 0 for no compression up to 9
>   for maximum compression.
>
> ```
> If -1 is used, the default compression of the zlib library is used which is 6.
> ```

**encoding**

> One of ZLIB_ENCODING_* constants.

**gzencode — Create a gzip compressed string**

```
<?php
$data = implode("", file("bigfile.txt"));
$gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
$fp = fopen("bigfile.txt.gz", "w");
fwrite($fp, $gzdata);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing "Content-type: application/x-gzip" headers when sending the file as a string?

It's possible Apache is re-running it through a gzip filter and that's causing issues.